# Configuration Management in AKS Deployment with Azure Pipelines for Different Environments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I have created a ASP.NET Core WebAPI and deployed in an Dev Environment (Kubernetes) using Azure Pipelines. How can I update the configuration in the pipeline if I need to publish the same API in another environment (eg. SIT). Since I have different settings/configuration for Dev and SIT environments.
Kindly guide me.

Comment: Not get your response for several days. What configuration do you want to update, please describe in detail.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT, Sorry for the late response. I am delpoying the API to a Kubernetes Cluster using AKS through Azure Pipelines. The database connection strings are in 'appsettings.json'. The problem occurs when I want to deploy the same API to other environments like QA/UAT/Prod. Since each environment is having separate databases.

Comment: You can use `Replace Tokens` extension to replace the database connection string in appsettings.json. Please view the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use release variables to do this. Feel free to reachout if you need any assistance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-specify-variables-i-want-to-edit-when-a-release-is-created

Answer (score 0):

> The problem occurs when I want to deploy the same API to other
>   environments like QA/UAT/Prod. Since each environment is having
>   separate databases

For this issue , there are several ways to achieve this. You can add [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) extension to the job to replace the database connection string in appsettings.json.

[image]

You can define your variable like below:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "#{connectstring}#"
  }
}
```

You can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637328/set-connection-string-in-azure-devops-pipeline) and [lab](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/kubernetes/#lab-scenario) for details.

Here are some reference for the same issue:

[Replacing database connection strings in the Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53674527/replacing-database-connection-strings-in-the-docker-image)

[Set Json Property task to replace the ConnectionStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113690/how-to-fix-in-azure-devops-connection-string-is-null-despite-setting-variable-i)

Comment: If this is the case, we might need different build pipelines for each environment right?

Comment: I think it is not necessary to use different build pipelines,you just need to replace different connection string in `replace tokens` task .Then generate different artifacts, choose different artifacts in the release to deploy to the corresponding environment.

Comment: Replace tokens in 'appsetting.json' will not work. Because in build pipeline I am pushing the Image to ACR with the replaced values. And I have only one build pipeline. In release pipeline I am deploying in to multiple environments using AKS. So same appsettings will be getting deployed in all the environments.

Comment: You can set approvals for the stages to control which environment to deploy to.Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/index?view=azure-devops).